# pandas sort values in pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I have a dataframe and I want to get all rows grouped in id where after row with country = russia and month = march is followed by a line with country != russia

input dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'fruit': ['pear','pear','pear','banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'apricot', 'pear','watermelon','pear','banana', 'banana', 'banana','banana', 'melon', 'cherry','banana', 'kiwi', 'kiwi', 'kiwi'],
'country': ['france','france', 'france', 'russia', 'russia', 'russia','russia', 'france','russia','usa', 'russia', 'ghana','ghana','ghana', 'ghana', 'albania','andorra', 'russia', 'russia', 'russia'],
'id': ['01','01','01','01','01','01','02','02','03','03','011', '011', '011','011', '6', '6','6', '5', '5', '5'],
'id1': ['01','01','01','01','01','01','02','02','03','03','011', '011', '011','011', '6', '6','6', '5', '5', '5'],
'month': ['january','september','january','january','september','january','january', 'september','march','march', 'november', 'march', 'january','january', 'march', 'january','july', 'march', 'march', 'april']        
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['fruit','country', 'id','id1', 'month'])
```

[image]

I made pivot table with `pd.pivot_table(df, values='id', index=['fruit','country'], columns='id1', aggfunc='count')` and i got many unuseless rows, where i have `NaN` or very small figures.

[image]

How to sort pivot table to get rows with figures no less than 3? Can anyone see the problem

I need to get this dataframe

```
data = {'fruit': ['banana', 'banana', 'kiwi','pear'],
'country': [ 'ghana','russia','russia','france'],
'01': [np.nan,3,np.nan,3],
'011': [3,1,np.nan,np.nan],
'5': [np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['fruit','country', '01', '011','5'])
```

[image]

Comment: Your input data is not the same as shown in the picture.

Comment: @Corralien thank you, I've just corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `df2` is your pivot table, you can do this:

```py
row_mask = np.any((df2 >= 3).values, axis=1)
col_mask = np.any((df2 >= 3).values, axis=0)
df2.loc[row_mask, col_mask]
```

```
            id1  01     011       5
fruit   country             
banana  ghana   NaN     3.0     NaN
        russia  3.0     1.0     NaN
kiwi    russia  NaN     NaN     3.0
pear    france  3.0     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this your desired outcome? It is "to get rows with figures no less than 3", but different from your outcome picture..

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['fruit','country'], columns='id1', values='id', aggfunc='count')
df['total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
df.drop(df.loc[df['total']<3].index, inplace=True)
df.dropna(how='all', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Output

```
         id1    01  011 02  5   total
fruit   country                 
banana  ghana   NaN 3.0 NaN NaN 3.0
banana  russia  3.0 1.0 NaN NaN 4.0
kiwi    russia  NaN NaN NaN 3.0 3.0
pear    france  3.0 NaN 1.0 NaN 4.0
```